# I can not figure out my problem with SpreadsheetView in Swift

Tags: swift

Help!  I can't figure out my issue with SpreadsheetView.  The line I am having issue with is when I assign spreadsheetView.datasource = self.  It says it unwrapped an optional value and returned nil.  Here's my code.

```
import UIKit
import SpreadsheetView

class InventoryViewController: UIViewController, SpreadsheetViewDataSource, SpreadsheetViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView!

    var header = [String]()

    var data = [[String]]()



    enum Sorting {

        case ascending

        case descending



        var symbol: String {

            switch self {

            case .ascending:

                return "\u{25B2}"

            case .descending:

                return "\u{25BC}"

            }

        }

    }

    func downloadFile()-> URL{

        let url =  URL(string: "http://192.168.1.125:8000/newheights.txt")!

        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

        let localURL = url

        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in

            if let localURL = localURL {

                if let string = try? String(contentsOf: localURL) {

                    print(string)

                }

            }

            }.resume()

        return localURL

    }

    var sortedColumn = (column: 0, sorting: Sorting.ascending)



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        spreadsheetView.dataSource = self

        spreadsheetView.delegate = self



        spreadsheetView.register(HeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: HeaderCell.self))

        spreadsheetView.register(TextCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: TextCell.self))

        let localURL = downloadFile()

        let data = try! String(contentsOf: localURL, encoding: .utf8)

            .components(separatedBy: "\r\n")

            .map { $0.components(separatedBy: "\t") }

        header = data[0]

        self.data = Array(data.dropFirst())

    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        spreadsheetView.flashScrollIndicators()

    }



    // MARK: DataSource



    func numberOfColumns(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {

        return header.count

    }



    func numberOfRows(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {

        return data.count - 1

    }



    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, widthForColumn column: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 140

    }



    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, heightForRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {

        if case 0 = row {

            return 60

        } else {

            return 44

        }

    }



    func frozenRows(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func frozenColumns(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }



    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {

        if case 0 = indexPath.row {

            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: HeaderCell.self), for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell

            cell.label.text = header[indexPath.column]



            cell.setNeedsLayout()



            return cell

        } else {

            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: TextCell.self), for: indexPath) as! TextCell

            if indexPath.row < data.count+1{

                cell.label.text = data[indexPath.row][indexPath.column]}

            return cell

        }

    }



    /// Delegate



    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if case 0 = indexPath.row {

            if sortedColumn.column == indexPath.column {

                sortedColumn.sorting = sortedColumn.sorting == .ascending ? .descending : .ascending

            } else {

                sortedColumn = (indexPath.column, .ascending)

            }

            data.sort {

                let ascending = $0[sortedColumn.column] < $1[sortedColumn.column]

                return sortedColumn.sorting == .ascending ? ascending : !ascending

            }

            spreadsheetView.reloadData()

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure your spreadsheet view in your storyboard is wired to your outlet.

Comment: Can someone assist me further?

Comment: Where did you get SpreadsheetView?

Comment: kishikawakatsumi's git

Comment: Can you help further?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so update.  I figured out my first problem by linking it to my viewcontroller but, I encountered a second problem.  My new problem is an error replacing the old one called EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 2, address=0x1b487d940).  I assume the address is not as important as the code but I included it anyways.  Should this go on a new post or can it stay here?